# "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI" when link has query id 'https://someurl/organisation/50'

Tags: redirect, instagram-api

Basically when i add 'https://someurl/organisation/' to Valid redirect URIs it doesn't work as intended because url contains id in the end. How i should form valid url for developer console for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put that id parameter as query param rather than path param.

Alternatively, to get the id param in your auth callback handler - you can use `state` param of OAuth2 to pass that info.

In that case - you can still host the handler on `https://someurl/organisation/` - have it registered on the developer console. And pass the id: `50` as `state` param which you will get back in the redirect from Instagram.